# CircleCI: build of Meteor 2.2 docker application - failing

Tags: node.js, docker, meteor, circleci, circleci-workflows

## How to get this error?

I am using Meteor 2.2 with Node 12.16.1 and CircleCI compiler @ version: 2.1 with latest docker image.

For a base I am using custom made docker "meteor-launchpad"

***I have decided to upgrade our Meteor from 1.11.1 to 2.2***

## Failure occurs on command in script:

`meteor build --directory "$APP_BUNDLE_DIR" --server-only`

"$APP_BUNDLE_DIR" is set during "meteor-launchpad" image creation (it already is set in image):

`ENV APP_BUNDLE_DIR /opt/meteor/dist`

### This error was not (and is not) existing in 1.11.1 Meteor version

### This error is **NOT** existing during image creation on my local server with Ubuntu 20

I have developed custom launchpad and added a way to use any Meteor release. Effect is that on Meteor 1.11.1 it is able to create image on CircleCI.

Not special user is being used on system (base image). It is standard: root @ debian:jessie

For node: user node is created with group node:

```
RUN groupadd -r node && useradd -m -g node node
```

I have tried giving access to some groups for users, but it has no effect:

```
RUN usermod -aG staff node
RUN usermod -aG node root
```

Flag for Meteor is set in launchpad: `METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=true`

**I am not sure where to dig for more information to resolve that issue. Any ideas how to approach fixing that error? It says PERM error which suggest some privileges issues but installation is handled by `root` user. Is there any environment value I need to set for CircleCI?**

## Detailed error from CircleCI (2.1) using Meteor (2.2):

```
[-] Building Meteor application...


Even with METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER or --allow-superuser, permissions in your app
directory will be incorrect if you ever attempt to perform any Meteor tasks as
a normal user. If you need to fix your permissions, run the following command
from the **** of your project:

  sudo chown -Rh <username> .meteor/local

/****/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1j8auib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:218
      throw error;
      ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile '/tmp/mt-1kbgw6u.nlqy/plugin.npm-check.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/resolve/.editorconfig' -> '/tmp/mt-1kbgw6u.nlqy/plugin.npm-check.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/.temp-ttjf6y.m2q6h/node_modules/resolve/.editorconfig'
    at Object.copyFileSync (fs.js:1907:3)
    at /****/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1j8auib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fs/tools/fs/files.ts:1642:23
    at copyFile (/****/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1j8auib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fs/tools/fs/files.ts:1697:3)
    at Object.cp_r (/****/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1j8auib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fs/tools/fs/files.ts:549:5)
    at /tools/isobuild/meteor-npm.js:429:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at copyNpmPackageWithSymlinkedNodeModules (/tools/isobuild/meteor-npm.js:422:29)
    at /tools/isobuild/meteor-npm.js:358:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.rebuildIfNonPortable (/tools/isobuild/meteor-npm.js:345:27)
    at /tools/isobuild/bundler.js:428:19
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/****/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1j8auib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:191:9)
    at Function.readDirsFromJSON (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:427:9)
    at /tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2573:34
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/****/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1j8auib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:186:9)
    at Function.readFromDisk (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:2565:7)
    at Object.readJsImage (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:3568:18)
    at /tools/isobuild/isopack.js:897:28
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/****/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1j8auib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:186:9)
    at Isopack._loadUnibuildsFromPath (/tools/isobuild/isopack.js:894:7)
    at /tools/packaging/tropohouse.js:521:21
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/****/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1j8auib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:186:9)
    at /tools/packaging/tropohouse.js:520:13
    at Object.enterJob (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:388:12)
    at /tools/packaging/tropohouse.js:515:22
    at Object.enterJob (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:388:12)
    at Object.download (/tools/packaging/tropohouse.js:427:20)
    at /tools/packaging/tropohouse.js:613:18
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:609:21
    at /****/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1j8auib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:43:40
 => awaited here:
    at Promise.await (/****/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1j8auib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:60:12)
    at Object.forkJoin (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:641:6)
    at exports.Tropohouse.downloadPackagesMissingFromMap (/tools/packaging/tropohouse.js:609:18)
    at /tools/project-context.js:857:25
    at Object.enterJob (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:388:12)
    at /tools/project-context.js:856:20
    at /tools/packaging/catalog/catalog.js:100:5
    at Object.capture (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:283:5)
    at Object.catalog.runAndRetryWithRefreshIfHelpful (/tools/packaging/catalog/catalog.js:99:31)
    at ProjectContext._downloadMissingPackages (/tools/project-context.js:855:13)
    at /tools/project-context.js:300:9
    at Object.enterJob (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:388:12)
    at ProjectContext._completeStagesThrough (/tools/project-context.js:290:18)
    at /tools/project-context.js:282:12
    at Function.run (/****/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1j8auib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/tool-env/tools/tool-env/profile.ts:289:14)
    at ProjectContext.prepareProjectForBuild (/tools/project-context.js:281:13)
    at /tools/cli/commands.js:1010:20
    at Object.capture (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:283:5)
    at Object.main.captureAndExit (/tools/cli/main.js:275:29)
    at buildCommand (/tools/cli/commands.js:1007:8)
    at /tools/cli/commands.js:948:25
    at Function.run (/****/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1j8auib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/tool-env/tools/tool-env/profile.ts:289:14)
    at /tools/cli/commands.js:946:18
    at /****/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1j8auib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:43:40
 => awaited here:
    at Promise.await (/****/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.2.0.1j8auib.qcbe++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:60:12)
    at /tools/cli/main.js:1529:7 {
  errno: -1,
  syscall: 'copyfile',
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: '/tmp/mt-1kbgw6u.nlqy/plugin.npm-check.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/resolve/.editorconfig',
  dest: '/tmp/mt-1kbgw6u.nlqy/plugin.npm-check.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/.temp-ttjf6y.m2q6h/node_modules/resolve/.editorconfig'
}
```

Comment: have you already tried the command suggested right above the error?

Comment: Yes, basically it does nothing (tested for user: root)

Answer (score 3):

CircleCI has documented a *particular* solution for a *particular* incompatibility between CircleCI's default `Docker 17.09.0-ce` and the NodeJS executor of `NodeJS > 14.9.0`:

https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360050934711

If using the `setup_remote_docker` key in your CircleCI config, setting the Docker version like so resolves the issue:

```
      - setup_remote_docker:
          version: 19.03.13
```